# Append to a text file using WriteAllLines

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code to write in a text file. My problem is that every time the following code is executed it empties the txt file and creates a new one. Is there a way to append to this txt file?

```
string[] lines = {DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString(),DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(), message, type, module };
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logger.txt"), lines);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`File.AppendAllLines` should help you:

```
string[] lines = {DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString(),DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(), message, type, module };
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logger.txt"), lines);
```

Comment: AppendAllText does not accept a String Array as the second parameter. The correct answer should be one of those below using the AppendAllLines method.

Comment: Just a note, this will not clear existing items in text file.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`File.AppendAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691.aspx). That should do it

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(
       HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logger.txt"), 
       lines);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx); if the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.

```
string[] lines = { DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(), message, type, module };

using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logger.txt"), true))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(lines);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this :

```
string[] lines = {DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString(),DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(), message, type, module };
          if (!File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logger.txt")))
          {
              System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logger.txt"), lines);
          }
          else
          {
              System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logger.txt"), lines);
          }
```

So if file is not exists it will create and write in file and if file exists it will append on file.

Comment: Not required. AppendAllLines will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no append lines in System.IO.File

Comment: @user1292656 : Please check on net AppendAllLines method is there and and you are talking about AppendLines, god knows what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use

public static void AppendAllLines(
    string path,
    IEnumerable contents
)

Answer (score 0):

three function are available ..File.AppendAllLine ,FileAppendAllText and FileAppendtext..you can try as u like...

Answer (score 0):

In all the above cases I prefer to use using to make sure that open and close file options will be taken care of.