# How to add line to text with StreamWriter?

Tags: c#

How to add a line to already existing file with StreamWriter? I Tried doing researches but nothing fits my needs.

I have this:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(appdata + @"\FILE.txt"))
{ 
   writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "newline"); 
}
```

And instead of replacing the text that is in the file I want to add a new line to it. Also, if the file doesn't exist, it should create itself. This code does in fact what I described, but it replaces (so for example if you click once it's `newline` and then again it's just `newline2`. `newline` is not there. It should look like:

`newline` <

```
        I want this effect
```

`newline2`<

and then add more after a new line.

Comment: for just adding lines, I recommend `File.AppendAllLines` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379136/append-to-a-text-file-using-writealllines

Comment: I found the duplicate by Googling "c# append to text file", you should spend some more time searching before asking questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flag in the [constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328969(v=vs.71).aspx) to advocate the writer to append the new content at end of file. You can pass `true` as argument to append new content instead of replacing whole content:

```
new StreamWriter(appdata + @"\FILE.txt", append: true);
```

Comment: I added "true" and it's still removing content of the file replacing it with new

Comment: that shouldn't be the case, are you sure?

Comment: my exact code
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(appdata + @"\important.txt"))
    {
     writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + generatedCode.Text, true);
    }
the generatedCode Text is changed every click and the file updates with the click too (after the text change)

and it doesnt work.. still

Comment: That's not what Ehsan and me were proposing. You have to add the true to the SteramWriter constructor, not the WriteLine call.

Comment: @NorteX please see the code snippet posted carefully :)

Comment: Okay, it works now, sorry for being incautious...

Answer (score 1):

Use the constructor taking an additional `bool append` parameter:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(appdata + @"\FILE.txt", true )) {
```